# Replace string Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing the following thing to replace some part of the string. I want to replace all three occurence of the string but it is not working.

```
 var  hdnval = document.getElementById("hdnColgval").value = response;
$("#ddcolgs").val($("#ddcolgs").val().replace(/'+hdnval+'/g, response));
```

Comment: If you like jQuery, you'd love [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to append a string to a `regex` which will cause errors. If you are simply replacing strings, try this:

```
var hdnval = document.getElementById("hdnColgval").value = response;
$("#ddcolgs").val($("#ddcolgs").val().replace(hdnval, response));
```

If the value of `#hdnColgval` is supposed to be a regex expression, use this:

```
var hdnval = document.getElementById("hdnColgval").value = response;
var regex = new Regex(hdnval, 'g');
$("#ddcolgs").val($("#ddcolgs").val().replace(regex, response));
```

Comment: hi Rory McCrossan thxs 4 u answer it really helped.........One more question......I have a string  '|lcol~-1|lcol~-1'  now i need to find wether the string contains '-1' using javascript

Comment: @vidyasagar85 you can use `test()`, like this: `'|lcol~-1|lcol~-1'.test('-1')` which will return true/false depending on whether `-1` was found.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a regular expression from a variable in that way.. try:

```
.replace(new RegExp(hdnval, 'g'), response);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your variable in the regex, use the new Regexp method:

```
var  hdnval = document.getElementById("hdnColgval").value,
         re = new RegExp(hdnval, "g");

$("#ddcolgs").val(function(i,v) {
   return v.replace(re, response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is almost correct, jssut remove the quotes. You don't need them

```
var  hdnval = document.getElementById("hdnColgval").value = response;
$("#ddcolgs").val($("#ddcolgs").val().replace(/hdnval/g, response));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ddcolgs").val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(RegExp(hdnval,'g'), response);
}
```